# Why is Python's Hashlib not strongly typed?

Tags: python, hashlib

Python is supposed to be strongly typed.

For instance: `'abc'['1']` won't work, because you're expected to provide an integer there, not a string. An error wil be raised and you can go on and correct it.

But that's not the case with hashlib. Indeed, try the following:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5('abc') #Works OK        

hashlib.md5(1) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: md5() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not int

hashlib.md5(u'abc') #Works, but shouldn't : this is unicode, not str.

haslib.md5(u'é')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Of course, it does not fail because of a `TypeError`, but because of `UnicodeEncodeError`. `UnicodeEncodeError` is supposed to be raised when you attempt to encode unicode to a string.

I think I'm not too far from the truth when my guess is that Hashlib silently attempted to convert unicode to a string.

Now. I agree, hashlib indicated that the argument to `hashlib.md5()` should be a string or a read-only buffer, which a unicode string is.
But this actually goes to show that it actually is not: `hashlib.md5()` will work properly with strings and that's about it.

Of course, the main problem this causes is that you will get an exception with some unicode strings, and not with some others.

Which leads me to my questions. First, do you have an explanation as to why hashlib implements this behavior? Second, is it considered an issue? Third, is there a way to fix this without changing the module itself?

Hashlib is basically an example, there are several other modules that behave the same when provided unicode strings - which leads you to an uncomfortable situation where your program will work with ASCII input but completely fail with accents.

Comment: You should read up on duck typing. Basically, since a unicode object acts like a string most of the time, you can typically use it as a string.

Comment: Indeed, but my main problem was actually that if you happen to use non-ASCII chars, you've got a problem as you're not there to specify .encode('utf-8') or whatever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not just hashlib - Python 2 handles Unicode in a number of places by trying to encode it as ascii. This was one of the big changes made for Python 3.

In Python 3, strings are unicode, and they behave as you expect: there's no automatic conversion to bytes, and you have to encode them if you want to use bytes (e.g. for MD5 hashing). I believe there are hacks using `sys.setdefaultencoding` that enable this behaviour in Python 2, but I'd advise against using them in production, because they'll affect any code running in that Python instance.

Comment: Interresting, I was unaware that Python3 changed this. So you get TypeErrors in Python3 whenever you use Unicode in places where Strings should be used? Pretty unfortunate that so many libraries require Python 2.X then.

Comment: @Thomas Orozco: Yes, except strings *are* unicode in Python 3. You get errors if you try to use unicode in place of bytes, or vice versa. Library support has got quite a bit better in the last year or so.

Comment: So the 'new' unicode of python3 is string, and what used to be strings is now bytes? Got this, thanks for the info. (Unfortunately I use mostly Django so I guess I'll just have to wait!)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Doesn't look like Django will be ported any time soon, though.

Comment: Django 1.5 is the first version of Django to support Python 3. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/python3/

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of the Python 2.x C API making it convenient to pass Unicode objects in to C APIs expecting a string.

See the PyArg_ParseTuple* call in [_hashopenssl.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fcf4d547bed8/Modules/_hashopenssl.c#l457).

It will attempt to encode a Unicode object into a byte string when parsing it for the 's*' argument.  If it cannot be encoded, the error will be raised.  The correct thing to do is to always call .encode('utf-8') or whatever other codec your application demands before attempting to use anything Unicode in a context where only a raw byte stream makes sense.

Python 3.x fixes this.  Instead you will always get a friendly:

**TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing**

Instead of any automatic encoding.